# NameError: name 'var1' is not defined python

Tags: python, string, variables, var, nameerror

randomly I get the error "NameError: name 'var1' is not defined" in my python script. This only happens occasionally though which is the issue. How can I solve this?

```
for i in range(len(list)):
    try:
        driver.get(url)

        innerHTML = driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(innerHTML, "html.parser")
        
        for i in soup.select("#SOMETHING"):
            global var1
            var1= i.text
            print(var1)

        global URL
        URL = driver.current_url
        print(URL)

        database.execute("INSERT INTO Database VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", (str(var1), str(var2), str(var3), str(var4), str(var5), str(var6), str(var7)))
        database.commit()
   except:
      pass

        driver.close()
        driver.quit()
```

Comment: Can you spot a path through the code where `var1` won't be assigned a value?  I can.

Comment: Maybe is not entering in the for where you declare the variable.
`for i in soup.select("#SOMETHING"):`
so when you call the variable in the line `database.execute("INSERT INTO Database VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", (str(var1), str(var2), str(var3), str(var4), str(var5), str(var6), str(var7)))` **var1 is not defined**

Comment: `global` doesn't do anything at module scope. Its used to assign variables at global scope in functions, methods, etc... Global variables only come into existance on first assignment. If `var1` isn't defined, it means that assignment didn't happen - the `for` loop didn't have anything to process.

Comment: What would you like to happen when there is nothing selected in `soup.select("#SOMETHING")`?

Comment: var2 and etc aren't defined either. They will be your next bug. You seem to expect 7 values from the select and those are what you insert? You could place them in a list and if that list is anything other than len 7, raise an error.

Answer (score 0):

Variables only come into existence on first assignment. If a variable doesn't exist, it means that the code that assigns it didn't run (or `del` deleted it). `global` doesn't change that. `global` tells that code not in the global scope (like a function) should assign to the global namespace, not local. It doesn't actually create the variable (see rule above). It has no meaning with this code and should be removed.

`var1` is assigned in a `for` loop, but only if that `for` actually has data to process. If `soup.select("#SOMETHING")` doesn't find anything, the `for` exitss and `var1` isn't assigned.

But that's only part of your problem. If the select does find something, you keep overwriting `var1` but not assigning to the `var2` and etc... variables used later. It looks like a list of vars is more what you want.

```
for i in range(len(list)): # <-- this is an error too. Don't know what to replaceit with
    try:
        driver.get(url)

        innerHTML = driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(innerHTML, "html.parser")
        values = [i.text for i in soup.select("#SOMETHING")]
        if len(values) != 7:
            print("ERROR: All Bad")
            exit(2)

        URL = driver.current_url
        print(URL)

        database.execute("INSERT INTO Database VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", values)
        database.commit()
    except:
        print("Um, super bad")
        pass

    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
```